# body in a php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, document-body

I created a custom index.php for a wordpress theme. I just renamed the .html to .php file. Everything seems to work fine except there are extra characters printed if I run the page.

These characters are printed at start of the body area in the browser :  " --> "

I am confused as to from where these characters are printed. I can create a .php with complete html contents right? Or do I need to do some modification.

Comment: please post some code that looks like a comment tag end

Comment: no need, may be if u copy code from some other webpage you get that clean all spaces once it will go

Comment: if possible add code here solving will be easier

Answer (score 0):

`<!--this is a HTML comment line -->`

If you forget to delete last `-->` characters after deleting the first part, you might be seeing that. We cannot know without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

As answer to the last question, you can mix php and plain HTML. Whenever you are writing php your code must be within

```
<?php   ... CODE HERE ...  ?>
```

Inline php however is not a good programming pattern in my opinion.